# How to pass long to the spring PUT controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, post, put

I have controller:

```
@RestController
public class AdminController {

    @PutMapping("/path/max_file_size")
    public void setMaxFileSize(@ModelAttribute MaxFileSizeDto size) {
        System.out.println(size.getSize());
    }

    public static class MaxFileSizeDto {
        private long size;

        public long getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void setSize(long size) {
            this.size = size;
        }
    }
}
```

I send htpp request with post[image]man:

but I always gets 0 for

```
size.getSize()
```

what do I wrong?

Comment: Could you please try `private Long size;` (along with setter, getter) instead of `private long size;` ? Using Long object, not the primitive.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna at this case i see null instead of 0

Comment: @shinjw in case of  RequestBody I get 415

Comment: Then you could try by selecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` in post man.

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna - it is working - thanks

Comment: Can I post it as a answer that you can accept?

Comment: @Ataur Rahman Munna you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Adding model you should remember that, `Model` and `Controller` should be segregated. That means keep your model in another package or class.For posting/putting data you should use `Object`(String, Integer,Long) instead of `primitive`(int, long etc).

Suppose your Model Class

**MaxFileSizeDto.java**

```
public static class MaxFileSizeDto {
    private Long size;

    public Long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(Long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

And your controller class will be:

```
@RestController
public class AdminController {

    @PutMapping("/path/max_file_size")
    public void setMaxFileSize(@ModelAttribute MaxFileSizeDto size) {
        System.out.println(size.getSize());
    }
}
```

When you sent data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then your data will be sent in this format and directly bind in `@ModelAttribute` defined class.

```
param1=data1&param2=data2&param3=data3
```

However postman internally send the data in this format.
If you want to send data as a `@RequestBody` then you should use json data saying that your content type is `application/json`. To do that you should select `raw` radio button from postman and select `application/json` from drop down.*(last element in the row)*
In these case data will be

```
{
    "size":123456
}
```

Comment: but what if I don't want pass data in url and I don't want json

Comment: You should not pass the data in url. your `browser / http requester` do that conversion internally. You could inspect the http message and see.

Comment: Do you know how to acheve it with form data?

Comment: Then it should be a multipart request as well as a receiver in controller side.

Comment: A tons of example you found in internet.